# Constructing a differential equation with a given solution and nonsolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Construct a differential equation for which $y(t)=6$ is a solution function but $y(t)=8$ is not a solution function.

How I thought about it was knowing that $y'(t) = 0$ for both. Does this mean that $dy/dt$ = 0?
I also tried to make $y(t)=(t-6)/(t-8)$ but wasn't sure if this was the correct way to go about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try instead a solution $y= 6 + Cx$. Then $y' = C$ and the differential equation $xy' + 6 = y$ is pretty clear.

Comment: "Does this mean that dy/dt = 0?" For your *particular* solution of $y=6$, then yes. But this $y$ doesn't have to be the general solution to the DE that you construct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Define $u(t)$ by $y(t) = u(t) + 6$, so that we're looking for an equation for which $u(t) = 0$ is a solution but $u(t) = 2$ is not. The zero function is a solution to any linear, homogeneous equation, so it's enough to choose such an equation for which $u(t) = 2$ is not a solution.

> **Additional hint** A simple example of such an equation is $u' = u$.